# Capture PiCam photos and append folder with different filenames

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, append

I am capturing a daily photo with my PiCam and saving it to a folder. How can I append each image into the folder location using the filenames "Monday.jpg", "Tuesday.jpg", etc.

The current code works but rewrites the file name week1.jpg

```
days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']

def capture():
    camera.start_preview()
    sleep(5)
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Pictures/week1.jpg')
    camera.stop_preview()
```

I know that this code is rewriting the image file as "week1.jpg" but I cannot figure how to append a new file to the location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use current time as follow:

First, put this to the starting lines of your file.

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Then, you can save your pictures with different filenames with format 'Day-YearMonthDateHourMinSec.jpg' as follows.

```
def capture():
    camera.start_preview()
    sleep(5)
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Pictures/' + datetime.now().strftime('%A-%y%m%d%H%M%S.jpg'))
    camera.stop_preview()
```

datetime.now() returns datetime object that represents current time and strftime() method allows you to print the current time with format that you defines.